# Method for Returning Top 'n' Values from 'x' Tables and Joining

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write a query that returns the top 3 values from each table, then joins the tables together on their shared year.

```
SELECT los_ty_year AS `year`, `los_ty_#_nights`, los_ty_nights_frequency, reg_ty_region, reg_ty_region_frequency

FROM  ( SELECT los_ty_year, `los_ty_#_nights`, los_ty_nights_frequency
        FROM ty_jp_kr_length_of_stay
        WHERE los_ty_year = 2017
        ORDER BY los_ty_nights_frequency desc
        LIMIT 3) T1

JOIN (
        SELECT reg_ty_year, reg_ty_region, reg_ty_region_frequency
        FROM ty_jp_kr_region_residence
        WHERE reg_ty_year = 2017
        ORDER BY reg_ty_region_frequency DESC
        LIMIT 3 ) T2
        
ON T1.los_ty_year = T2.reg_ty_year
LIMIT 3
```

Expected Output

```
year   los_ty_#_nights   los_ty_nights_freq   reg_ty_region   reg_ty_region_freq
2017   2_nights          .333                 south           .256
2017   3_nights          .244                 southwest       .195
2017   1_night           .215                 west            .137
```

My problem is that I always get duplicates for one of the columns, no matter how I seem to order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major problem with your current join logic is that all 3 top records from both subqueries share the same year 2017.  This means that your join is effectively a *cross join*, and should yield a result set with 9 records.  With MySQL 8+, we can handle this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT los_ty_year, `los_ty_#_nights`, los_ty_nights_frequency,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY los_ty_nights_frequency DESC) rn
    FROM ty_jp_kr_length_of_stay
    WHERE los_ty_year = 2017
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT reg_ty_year, reg_ty_region, reg_ty_region_frequency,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY reg_ty_region_frequency DESC) rn
    FROM ty_jp_kr_region_residence
    WHERE reg_ty_year = 2017
)

SELECT
    t1.los_ty_year AS year,
    t1.`los_ty_#_nights`,
    t1.los_ty_nights_frequency,
    t2.reg_ty_region,
    t2.reg_ty_region_frequency
FROM cte1 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY
    t1.rn;
```

Note that here we join the "first" record from the first subquery (actually a CTE) to the "first" record from the second subquery, and so on.